# Checking null values in Datatable Column while rendering using Jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using datatable to display my data. In one of my columns i am using a render to check the null if it is not null then display the data using split method.
The code is working but it gives a browser warning every time it finds a null value.

here is my code

```
{
  "mData": "address",
  "render": function(data, type, row) {
    if (data == null) { //do nothing}
      else {
        return data.split("\n").join("<br/>");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

here is the warning message I get

> **DataTables warning**: table id=tblrss - Requested unknown parameter 'address' for row 2, column 5. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Comment: Did you read the information provided in http://datatables.net/tn/4?

Comment: Your code, as provided, will give a syntax error and not run.

Comment: *Each cell in DataTables requests data, and when DataTables tries to obtain data for a cell and is unable to do so, it will trigger a warning, telling you that data is not available where it was expected to be*  - so give it some data: `if (data == null) { return "" }`?

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks yeah i forgot to return anything when it is null, that solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
{
  "mData": "address",
  "render": function(data, type, row) {
    return data ? data.split("\n").join("<br/>") : "";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    {
 "mData": "address",
 "render": function(data, type, row) {
  if (data == null) { return "" }
  else {
    return data.split("\n").join("<br/>");
  }
}
```

//adding something to return when null solved the problem thanks to @freedomn-m